# Moved Laravel dir to root of server now composer update fails

Tags: laravel-4, composer-php

I wanted the Laravel 4.1 package to be at the root of a particular web server so I took it out of it's "laravel" dir and moved it.

Used to be in: C:\www\mysite.dev\laravel

Now it is in: C:\www\mysite.dev

When I run `composer update` it chokes producing the error:

```
{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"mkdir(): No such file or directory","file":"C:\\www\\mysite.dev\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Filesystem\\Filesystem.php","line":302}}
```

How can I configure composer.json to compensate for this change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like problem with permissions.

Line 302 of Filesystem.php is the following (in bold):

`public function makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, $recursive = false, $force = false)
{
    if ($force)
    {
        return @mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
    }
    else
    {
302       return mkdir($path, $mode, $recursive);
    }
}`

Comment: Failed to mention this is on Windows 8. I found that line in the code, but couldn't see why it is failing. If it was a *nix flavor, I could understand the permissions problem.